# Xquery to compare the date values in an array and get the max date value

Tags: date, xslt, compare, xquery

In my xquery i have the condition to check  if (SP_TYPE_CD!="") and (max of the EndDate) in an array and return the  EndDate that meets this condition

Request:

```
`<CMS xmlns="*******************">
     <CMSService>          
        <CMSDetails AccountID="123456" CR="1000">
           <SA_INFO_LIST>
              <SA_INFO_LISTRow SA_ID="3484598047" ServiceAgreementType="OOVRPAY" ServicePointType="" SP_TYPE_CD="" Status="60" StartDate="2018-09-27" EndDate="2018-09-27"/>
              <SA_INFO_LISTRow SA_ID="3486640145" ServiceAgreementType="OOVRPAY" ServicePointType="" SP_TYPE_CD="" Status="60" StartDate="2018-04-26" EndDate="2018-04-26"/>
              <SA_INFO_LISTRow SA_ID="3487463777" ServiceAgreementType="ERES" ServicePointType="3135182884" SP_TYPE_CD="RESE" Status="70" StartDate="2018-04-06" EndDate=""/>
              <SA_INFO_LISTRow SA_ID="3482685560" ServiceAgreementType="OOVRPAY" ServicePointType="" SP_TYPE_CD="" Status="60" 
           </SA_INFO_LIST>
        </CMSServiceDetails>
     </CMSService>
  </CMS>
```

My Xquery:

```
for $SA_INFO_LISTRow in $StartServiceAllowedResponse/ns2:CMSService/ns2:CMSServiceDetails/ns2:SA_INFO_LIST/ns2:SA_INFO_LISTRow
    return

        if (($SA_INFO_LISTRow/@SP_TYPE_CD)and fn:max($SA_INFO_LISTRow/@EndDate))
        then <ns1:date>{(fn:data($SA_INFO_LISTRow/@EndDate)}</ns1:date>
        else ()
```

I am receiving error message when i run the xquery in jdeveloper

```
FORG0001: "2018-09-27": invalid value for cast/constructor: {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}double: error: double: Invalid double value: 2018-09-27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your query is schema-aware, the @endDate attribute (after atomization) will be xs:untypedAtomic, and the max() function attempts to convert xs:untypedAtomic values to dates. You need to tell the query processor to treat the values as dates, which you can do either by making your query schema-aware, or (more simply) by an explicit cast:

```
fn:max($SA_INFO_LISTRow/@EndDate/xs:date(.))
```

However, there are other problems with your query. This condition:

```
if (($SA_INFO_LISTRow/@SP_TYPE_CD) and fn:max($SA_INFO_LISTRow/@EndDate))
```

(when corrected) is simply asking whether a maximum date exists, and if there are any dates at all, then there will be a maximum, so this is fairly meaningless.

Also, you say you are looking for entries where @SP_TYPE_CD is not equal to "", but your code is looking for all entries where this attribute exists, regardless of its value.

I'm guessing that you actually want the maximum end date of all entries where @SP_TYPE_CD is not equal to "", and that would be (replacing your entire query)

```
    <ns1:date>
      {max(//SA_INFO_LISTRow[@SP_TYPE_CD != '']/@EndDate/xs:date(.))}
    </ns1:date>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I removed the if condition completely and i tried the statement you mentioned .ie..e   <ns1:date>{max($SA_INFO_LISTRow[@SP_TYPE_CD != '']/@EndDate/xs:date(.))}</ns1:date> . But i receive error message line 21, column 74: {http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors}FORG0001: "": invalid value for cast/constructor: {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}date: error: date: Invalid date value: wrong type:

Comment: If i correct the if statement and xquery: for $SA_INFO_LISTRow in $StartServiceAllowedResponse/ns2:CMServiceAgreementByAccountSearchService/ns2:CMServiceAgreementByAccountSearchServiceDetails/ns2:SA_INFO_LIST/ns2:SA_INFO_LISTRow
        return
        
       if ((($SA_INFO_LISTRow/@SP_TYPE_CD)!='')and fn:max(xs:string($SA_INFO_LISTRow/@EndDate)))
            then <ns1:date>{max($SA_INFO_LISTRow[@SP_TYPE_CD != '']/@EndDate/xs:date(.))}</ns1:date>
            else () . It runs but the result comes back with all dates where SP_TYPE_CD != ''. it is not getting max date. I m using xquery1.0

Comment: I didn't notice that some of your @EndDate values aren't actually dates. I don't think I can give you any more code unless you provide a more precise specification.